# missing images when using casperjs to generate pdf from slidify (HTML5) slides

Tags: javascript, r, pdf-generation, casperjs, slidify

### Overview

I am trying to generate a pdf doc from R markdown document (using ramnathv's slidify library, and the io2012 framework). This process is described briefly [here](https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/issues/348#issuecomment-35747309).

The one-liner he provides works perfectly, except that I don't see images in my pdf doc.

However, in the example given above which links to jtleek's repository (available [here](https://github.com/jtleek/modules/tree/master/01_DataScientistToolbox)), it appears that images are included in generated pdfs, successfully.

I am not sure if the problem lies with my javascript, or with the HTML code generated by slidify/R.

### Replicating the Problem

The problem can be replicated as follows :

```
casperjs makepdf.js http://jburos.github.io/test-slidify-to-pdf/index.html index.pdf 1000
```

[ NOTE: In order for the example to work, you have to have installed casperjs & phantomjs. ]

Where the contents of makepdf.js are:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({viewportSize:{width:1500,height:1000}});
var args = casper.cli.args;
var imgfile = (args[1] || Math.random().toString(36).slice(2))
casper.start(args[0], function() {
  this.wait(args[2], function(){
    this.captureSelector(imgfile, "slides");
  });
});

casper.run();
```

Alternatively, you can replicate the problem by cloning my git repository,

```
git clone git@github.com:jburos/test-slidify-to-pdf.git
cd test-slidify-to-pdf
casperjs makepdf.js  index.pdf 1000
```

Again, the problem is that the index.pdf doc does not include any images, which are rendered by index.html.

### Background

I would note that the full process has several steps:

1. Use R/slidify/knitR to convert

   - .Rmd file -> .md file
   - .md file -> .html file
2. Use casperjs to convert

   - .html file -> .pdf file

Alternate methods of generating a pdf from Rmd I've considered include:

1. using pandoc to generate beamer pdf: `pandoc index.md -t beamer -o index_beamer.pdf`

   - yields ``` ! LaTeX Error: File ``ifluatex.sty' not found. ```
2. using Chrome browser to print index.html to pdf

   - yields left-truncated image file, as described in the above post
3. using pandoc to generate pdf from md file:

   - yields pdf (not slideshow style) also not containing images

Many thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the detailed question. At first, I thought the issue was a reference problem, so I ran

```
casperjs makepdf.js index.html index.pdf 3000 --verbose=true --log-level=info
```

This gave no useful information, so I replaced one of the image `src`es with a base64 encoded image. This still did not show, so I knew it must be the Javascript or CSS. Indeed, removing everything except for the `img` tag produced the correct result. A binary search on the tags in the header (e.g., remove half, and see if images show) narrowed the problem down to `libraries/frameworks/io2012/css/default.css`. Another binary search (removing half the file and regenerating the PDF each time) narrowed it down to these two lines:

```
 margin-left: -450px;
 margin-top: -350px;
```

in the CSS for `slides > slide` (line 246-247 of this file). I was able to fix the problem by adding

```
<style type="text/css">
 slides > slide {
   margin-left:0;
   margin-top:0;
 }
</style>
```

Finally, I [submitted a pull request to your Github repo](https://github.com/jburos/test-slidify-to-pdf/pull/1) to fix the issue.

Since you are auto-generating this, you probably want to add an intermediate processing step that injects this CSS into the `.html` file, or--if your `default.css` is expected to be static and does not get regenerated--just remove the two `margin` styles from the delinquent CSS file directly.

[image: screenshot of solution]

Comment: You're right - and thank you - this does create a perfect PDF doc. The HTML, however, is not so pretty after this change ;) at least not on Chrome. Compare [your example](http://robertzk.github.io/test-slidify-to-pdf) to [the original](http://jburos.github.io/test-slidify-to-pdf/). I may end up using two different index.html docs, one to generate the pdf and another to display as HTML.